# Button submit без перезагрузки

Tags: php, html, ajax

решил создать простенький тест на php, может кто подсказать какой ajax код надо написать чтобы при нажатии на кнопку страничка не перезагружалась. 
        Вот что имею на данный момент :

```
<form action="test.php" method="post" class="ajax">
    <h5> <b>1.</b> Jak ... na imię?</h5>
       <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> masz <br>
       <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> mam <br>
       <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3"> mieć <br>
      <h5> <b>2.</b> ... matka bardzo dobrze gotuje.</h5>
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="1"> mój <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"> ją <br>
        <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="3"> moja <br>
<input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<?php
    error_reporting(0);

       $right = 0;
       $wrongt = 0;
          if ($_POST[radio]  == 1){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
          if ($_POST[radio2] == 3){$ot++;} else {$not++;}
          <p class = "right"> Правильных ответов: <?php echo $right; ?></p>
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

$answ1 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'radio');
$answ2 = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'radio2');

if ($answ1 !== null && $answ2 !== null) {
    $right = 0;
    $wrong = 0;
    $answ1 == 1 ? $right ++ : $wrong ++;
    $answ2 == 3 ? $right ++ : $wrong ++;
    exit(json_encode(['right' => $right, 'wrong' => $wrong]));
}
?>

<div id="iq"></div>
<form action="test.php" method="post" id="govnokod">
    <h5> <b>1.</b> Jak ... na imię?</h5>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="1"> masz <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="2"> mam <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="3"> mieć <br>
    <h5> <b>2.</b> ... matka bardzo dobrze gotuje.</h5>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="1"> mój <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="2"> ją <br>
    <input type="radio" name="radio2" value="3"> moja <br>
    <input type="submit" id="submit">
</form>
<script>
    document.querySelector('#govnokod').addEventListener('submit', function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        function Success(e) {
            if (req.readyState == 4) {
                if (req.status == 200) {
                    var res = JSON.parse(e.currentTarget.response);
                    document.querySelector('#iq').innerText = 'Правильно: ' + res.right + ' неправильно ' + res.wrong;
                }
            }
        }
        var answ1 = document.querySelector('input[name=radio]:checked') === null ? 0 : document.querySelector('input[name=radio]:checked').value;
        var answ2 = document.querySelector('input[name=radio2]:checked') === null ? 0 : document.querySelector('input[name=radio2]:checked').value;
        var params = "radio=" + answ1 + "&radio2=" + answ2;
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('POST', 'test.php', true);
        req.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        req.onreadystatechange = Success;
        req.send(params);
    })
</script>
```